# Tasky example compiles but will not run

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to work the Tasky example from the Xamarin site.  The solution builds without error, however when I try to run it with `Tasky.Core.Android` as the startup project, I get an error saying that it cannot be launched as startup project. I changed the startup project to TaskyAndroid and tried to run it and get the following error message

> Skipped Deploy: Project: TaskyAndroid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========

Consequently I can't continue.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this problem?

Comment: Core is a library, not an executable project.  TaskyAndroid is the project you need to run

Comment: Ok, thanks Jason.  Sorry about the delayed response